# Python module BeautifulSoup extracting anchors href

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

i am using BeautifulSoup module to select all href from html by this way:

```
def extract_links(html):
  soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
  anchors = soup.findAll('a')
  print anchors
  links = []
  for a in anchors:
    links.append(a['href'])
  return links
```

but sometime it failed by this error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\py\main.py", line 33, in <module>
urls = extract_links(page)
File "C:\py\main.py", line 11, in extract_links
links.append(a['href'])
File "C:\py\BeautifulSoup.py", line 601, in __getitem__
return self._getAttrMap()[key]
KeyError: 'href'
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Not all anchor tags will have an href attribute. You should check that the anchor has an href before you try to access that attribute.

```
if a.has_key('href')
  links.append(a['href'])
```

After checking some comments here, I think this is the most pythonic way of handling this case.

Comment: Thanks, but now ir return this error message: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\py\main.py", line 34, in <module>
    urls = extract_links(page)
  File "C:\py\main.py", line 11, in extract_links
    if 'href' in a.keys():
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable

Comment: @micheal You're putting `a` tags in your dictionary that dont have `href` attributes. Instead of asking the dictionary to cough up tags that may or may not gave an `href` attribute, ask the data if it does *before* putting it into the dictionary.

Comment: I think the new error is because a BeautifulSoup node isn't a dictionary, so `keys` isn't what you expect.

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

```
links = [a['href'] for a in anchors if a.has_key('href')]
```

Or, if you'd rather mutate an existing list

```
links = []
#...
links.extend(a['href'] for a in anchors if a.has_key('href'))
```

Comment: @Gabriel the docs might prefer it, but consider this. `s = BeautifulSoup('<html><body><a>href</a></body></html>'); 'href' in s.findAll('a')[0]` evaluates to `True`. `has_key` isn't leaky that way.

Answer (score 2):

**soup.findAll()** returns a list of "tags", that contain dictionaries of attributes. So you need to extract its attributes and work on them.

Taking your example and modifying, this is the code that works:

```
def extract_links(html):
  soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
  anchors = soup.findAll('a')
  print anchors
  links = []
  for a in anchors:
    if a.attrs.has_key('href'):
      links.append(a['href'])
return links
```

Answer (score 0):

The Pythonic way would be something like this:

```
for a in anchors:
    try:
        links.append(a['href'])
    except KeyError:
        pass
```

That simply skips any `<a>` tags without an href.

Comment: I think `has_key()` is more Pythonic than using errors for logic, but people seem to disagree about that in the community.

Comment: @MattLuongo: It depends what you're doing. I feel it's best expressed as "get the address of each link, and if it doesn't have a link, never mind", rather than "check if each link has an address, and if it does, get that." It doesn't help that `has_key` is deprecated for dictionaries, but `in` doesn't do the same thing for BS nodes.

Comment: I guess that's why `Tag` isn't a descendant of `dict`. Anyway, the deprecation isn't too relevant for that reason.

Comment: I agree with @MattLuongo. I had tried to find this in the documentation, but I forgot how bad python's docs are.

Comment: @tjarratt: Python's docs are fine, but BeautifulSoup isn't part of Python.

Answer (score 0):

You need to cast `a.attrs` to a `dict` first, then access the element.

```
links.append(dict(a.attrs)['href'])
```

Comment: Erm, I think you mean `links.append(dict(a.attrs)['href'])`..? But that doesn't handle the case where there are tags with `href`s.

Comment: You mean *without* `href`s? Then you're correct. My personal experience shows that I need to cast.

Comment: Ha, *without, thanks. I just meant that the above code doesn't cast `a.attrs` to a `dict`, it casts `a.attrs['href']` to a `dict`, which raises a `TypeError`.

Comment: oops, my bad... should've been more careful.

Answer (score 0):

1. I use the comment above, but the Warning occurs, so I change it to has_attr and pass

   ```
   if i.has_key("href"):
       print(i.string, i['href'])
   ```

   UserWarning: has_key is deprecated. Use has_attr("href") instead.

2.Pass——OK

```
if i.has_attr("href"):
    print(i.string, i['href'])
```