# How to use Beautiful soup to return destination from HTML anchor tags

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am using python 2 and Beautiful soup to parse HTML retrieved using the requests module

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

site = requests.get("http://www.stackoverflow.com/")
HTML = site.text
links = BeautifulSoup(HTML).find_all('a')
```

Which returns a list containing output which looks like `<a href="hereorthere.com">Navigate</a>`

The content of the attribute `href` for each anchor tag can be in several forms, for example it could be a javascript call on the page, it could be a relative address to a page with the same domain`(/next/one/file.php)`, or it could be a specific web address (http://www.stackoverflow.com/).

Using BeautifulSoup is it possible to return the web addresses of both the relative and specific addresses to one list, excluding all javascript calls and such, leaving only navigable links?

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9057809/python-module-beautifulsoup-extracting-anchors-href

Answer (score 0):

From the [BS docs](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/):

```
One common task is extracting all the URLs found within a page’s <a> tags:

for link in soup.find_all('a'):
    print(link.get('href'))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can filter out the href="javascript:whatever()" cases like this:

```
hrefs = []
for link in soup.find_all('a'):
    if link.has_key('href') and not link['href'].lower().startswith('javascript:'):
        hrefs.append(link['href'])
```